# sync contacts from Samsung S5 to Google account

Tags: samsung

my phone says it has synced contacts to my google account but when I log into the google account there are no contacts. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

• You sure that device doesn't have 2 different gmail accounts added. Might be the contacts backed up is in 'account 1' and you're looking for contacts in 'account 2'.

In case you have only one account added to the device, check this.

*Open Settings/Accounts/Google.*

Or

*Open Settings/Cloud and Accounts/Accounts/Google.*

Click your account, there you will see different options that can be enable or disable as per user choice.
Make sure 'Sync Contacts' is enabled for that particular account. Tap above 3 dots on the upper right corner on the screen and click 'Sync Now'.

Answer (score 0):

https://contacts.google.com

that is the site you have to go to see if you have any contacts on the google account. If there aren't any or there aren't one you synced, then it is probably phone sync problem.

I would rather suggest you to export all contact to storage then, import them, but while importing them import to google account as it gives you an option to do that. That should fix your problem. And, yes, delete the phone contacts after syncing, as they might cause "doubled contacts"

Make sure you have proper working internet connection while doing that, poor connection might also cause trouble while syncing.